# Page not found when accessing facebook Mobile OAuth

Tags: facebook

I'm using Nokia 5300. I'm getting Page not found when I'm trying to access the facebook mobile  OAuth. This was working before and I'm not sure if facebook changed something in their OAuth. Need help please.